# PostgreSQL Prepared statement not working with plsql if statement

Tags: php, postgresql, if-statement, prepared-statement, plpgsql

Ok, so I have this pgsql query here with a plsql if statement:

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
IF $1 & (SELECT group_flags FROM technic WHERE id = $2 LIMIT 1) > 0 THEN
   UPDATE technic SET group_flags = group_flags - $1 WHERE id = $2;
END IF;
END
$do$
```

And I am preparing it with the pg_prepare() PHP function and then executing it.
The problem is that pgsql returns this error -

```
Warning: pg_execute(): Query failed: ERROR: bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement "query1990094225" requires 0
```

But I have two parameters in the query...

And to make sure the syntax is not the problem, I replaced the parameters with integers and everything worked as expected.

I don't understand where the problem is.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: anonymous code blocks do not accept arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a `DO` statement with parameters, but fortunately you don't have to:

```
UPDATE technic
SET group_flags = group_flags - $1
WHERE id = $2
  AND (SELECT group_flags
       FROM technic
       WHERE id = $2
       LIMIT 1
      ) > 0
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer technically does not work how the original code did (made an edit but got rejected... ) but I fixed my code now and everything works perfectly. Very stupid of me to use and IF and not just WHERE...

Comment: I rejected the update because your simpler statement was not equivalent to the `DO` statement in the question. But if that is the statement you actually need, then it is much better to use it.